# Where to save your TWIG templates in Symfony framework

Tags: symfony, twig

What is the best place to keep your TWIG template and why?

```
app/Resources/views folder
```

or

```
YourBundle/Resources/views
```

Comment: [Official Symfony Best Practices: Template Locations](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/templates.html#template-locations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Traditionally, Symfony developers stored the application templates in
>   the Resources/views/ directory of each bundle. Then they used the
>   logical name to refer to them (e.g.
>   AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index.html.twig).
>
> But for the templates used in your application, it's much more
>   convenient to store them in the app/Resources/views/ directory.
>   [Syfmony Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/templates.html#template-locations)

- In Symfony 2, auto generated twig files were located in `YourBundle/Resources/views`
- In Symfony 3, auto generated twig files are located in `app/Resources/views`

Comment: any idea how to auto generate twig files in app/Resources/views for symfony 2.8?

Comment: you mind answering this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265685/symfony2-commandline-generation-of-twig-templates-under-global-folder

Answer (score 3):

When developing your application, best place is YourBundle/Resources/views. It will be more consistent and probably it will be easier to maintain and eventually, decouple your bundle for installation in other projects.

I find app/Resources/views useful to override other bundle's templates, for example when creating Error pages http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends of your bundles architecture. The point is to be **consistent with your current architecture**. 
From the official doc:

> For most projects, you should store everything inside the AppBundle

If you use a main bundle structure (like a big AppBundle with many small domain bundles) then you probably want to centralize your templates in App or the ressources of your main Bundle.
But if you use a functionnal bundles (like EmailBundle, UserBundle, Invoice Bundle) then you probably want to ignore the symfony best practice and put the concerned twig in these bundles.