# Symfony2 commandline generation of twig templates under global folder

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig, symfony-2.8

I'm using Symfony2.8 and when ever I use the command line for generating **controllers** and **twig templates** the templates are created under

`MyBundle/Resources/views/home/home.html.twig`

I want to follow the best practices suggested by [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/best_practices/templates.html#template-locations) and have it inside of the

`app/Resources/views/home/home.html.twig`

I could just cut and paste the twig file and then change the `{% extends %}` if necessary, but then I would have lesser hair on my head because I would be pulling it out.

So what do I type in the prompt so that it generates the controller in the `MyBundle` as usual BUT the twig files would be under the global `app/Resources/views`  folder

Thanks!

Edit: [new extended question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280852/symfony2-commandline-generation-of-twig-templates-under-global-folder-extended)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After playing a little with the path for template generation i succeeded  in placing the twig file inside the app/Resources/views/ folder.

Assuming that you have the standard architecture of a symfony2 app:
You could write the following path for the template when generator asks to specify the Templatename

```
Templatename (optional) [AppBundle:Post:get.html.twig]: ::../../../../app/Resources/views/Post/get.html.twig
```

Comment: created a new question as this is a new issue, please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280852/symfony2-commandline-generation-of-twig-templates-under-global-folder-extended